# Object does not save it state in Url.action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url.action

I am devloping an app using `jqueyrmobile` framework in .NET MVC3. I am creating a `ListView` using a loop

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index","Transaction",item)">
            <div style="vertical-align:text-top;padding:1px;font-size:large">  
              @Html.DisplayFor(modeItem => item.title)
              <span style="font-size:small;text-align:right">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modeItem => item.balance)
                .@Html.DisplayFor(modeItem => item.currency) 
              </span>
            </div>
          </a>
      </li>   
    }    
</ul>
```

This works fine and I am getting object `item` in `Index` Action of `Transaction` Controller; but for similer code for another page

```
 <ul data-role="listview">
       @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
          <li><a href="@Url.Action("optionDialog",item)" data-rel="dialog" >
          <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modeItem => item.brTitle)</div></a></li> 
        }       
    </ul>
```

I am getting null `item` object in `optionDialog` action. Though it made call to Action, the object is null. Any one please help me.

Comment: Can you post the `optionDialog` action?

Comment: public ActionResult optionDialog(BillReminderEntity brEn)
        {
           return View(brEn);
        }
and here object brEn is recieving null
is there any problem in local storage.should i try local storage of html5 for it?? @nemesv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution there is microsoft bug which dont work for some time to call to its own controller action after replacing

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("optionDialog",item)" data-rel="dialog" >
```

with

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("optionDialog","ControllerName",item)" data-rel="dialog" >
```

i got my result

Answer (score 0):

The problem it's that you're passing wrong the item to the action

```
 "@Url.Action("optionDialog",item)" <--- wrong
```

Tried like this

```
 "@Url.Action("optionDialog", new { fooParameter= item})"
```

Comment: it is also sending null object to Action